# lazy loading a tree and pagination at each node level - angular

Tags: angular, pagination, treeview, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll

Is there any componenets for angular which support lazy loading of tree, but also pagination as well at each node level?

There are a few options like
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-4.3.0/#/treetable

But none of them seem to support tree + lazy loading + pagination

Comment: You can easily make PimeNg Tree load lazy.

Comment: but i want to paginate across children also

Comment: What do you mean by paginating? it's not a table to have pagination